# Object does not exist when trying to EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_helpindex'

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run `sp_helpindex 'table1'` I'm returned indexes for that table.

When I try to run `exec sp_helptext 'sp_helpindex'` to look at the proc, I get:

> Object does not exist in this database.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It #worksforme. Try being absolutely explicit to avoid possible impostors (`exec master.sys.sp_helptext 'sys.sp_helpindex'`). Also, what version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: I just realised sybase stored procs are stored on another DB - doh!

Comment: Good thing I asked. :-P Current versions of SQL Server will produce "Could not find stored procedure '<name>'" for `EXEC` errors and "The object '<name>' does not exist in database 'master' or is invalid for this operation." for `sp_helptext` errors, which are both quite clear.